# Plotting horizontal line on already plotted data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I have to plot the density, which is constant as 1, onto a plot graphing the mass versus the radius, with relation to gravity. I need an additional line on the data to represent the constant density.

I've tried using axhline, but it always ends up making the red line with respect to the radius go to 1.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

start = 0
end = 1.0
rad_star = np.arange(start,end,0.01)
rho = 1 # constant density
G = 6.67e-11 # gravitational constant
mass = (4.0/3.0)*np.pi*rho*(rad_star)**3
grav = (4*G*np.pi*rho*rad_star)/3

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(rad_star,mass, 'b-') 
ax2.plot(rad_star,grav, 'r-')
# ax.hline is not working, everytime rho is mentioned, the radius 
line goes directly to one

ax1.set_title("Stellar Interior of Star with Constant Density")
ax1.set_ylabel('Mass ($M/M_{*}$)', color='blue') 
ax2.set_ylabel('Gravity ($g/g_{surface}$)', color='red')
ax1.set_xlabel('Radius ($r/R_{*}$)')
plt.show()
```

It's supposed to be 3 plots; a red linear straight line, a blue exponential line, and a black line equal to 1, which represents the density.

Comment: `ax1.axhline(1)` doesn't work?

Comment: Density is 1 on both the red and blue lines, isn't it? Are you intending to draw a 3D plot?

Comment: Yeah, and no it's not a 3D plot. I just tried the ax1.axhline(1) and that worked perfectly!